# What is wrong when an app is perpetually in need of updating from the Mac App Store?

Tags: ios, applications, software-update

I have an app called "UPAD Lite" that keeps appearing in the "updates" tab of app store. I have installed the update multiple times, but when the app store checked for updates, it would appear again. I have also tried deleting the app and reinstalling afterwards, and it still appeared in updates. I have also tried closing and reopening the app store, and it was still there.

Is this a problem with the app or with the app store? Is it possible to remove an app from the list of pending updates?

Comment: Just making sure: this is the same update appearing over and over again, right?

Comment: @NathanGreenstein yes, the same app, the same version.

Comment: I had one of those, Sketchbook Express. I supposedly added it on January 11, probably I did, but never used it. But then when I upgraded to Mountain Lion it would appear as "update available" every time. But after I let it go ahead and update about 5 times or so, it finally stopped appearing. I'm guessing it is a bug in App Store.